# git rebase --continue won't work

Tags: git, git-rebase

I did `git rebase master`, fixed the conflicts reported in a file, and then `git add` the file to resolve the conflict.  Then I did `git rebase --continue`, and got this:

> Applying: Fixed unit test
>
> No changes - did you forget to use 'git
>   add'? If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something
>   else already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this
>   patch.
>
> When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue". If
>   you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead. To
>   check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase
>   --abort".

Any idea what I am missing here? Should I do git rebase --skip?

Comment: What does a `git diff` show? If it shows no differences, then your rebase has resulted in an empty commit, and it's safe to skip.

Comment: git diff shows nothing.

Comment: As mentioned below, it is 99% sure it is the mentioned bug. If you do --skip you will lose the last commit, you could of course dig out whatever changes it includes and reimplement them when your rebase is finished. The alternative is `--abort` making the confit-change and starting over. :-(

Comment: `making the confit-change ` ?? huh?

Comment: For me `git rebase --skip`, `git add .`, then `git rebase --continue` again

Comment: my problem was I commited by hand after resolving. Only stage and then continue like @onmyway133

Comment: What I didn't realise in my case, was that there was more than one file which needed resolving.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you are in Mac OS X, then first of all you should disable `revisiond`, as it can mess with files in your work tree in the middle of rebase, causing unpredictable and broken behavior:

```
git config --global core.trustctime false
```

The issue is explained in [this article](http://www.git-tower.com/blog/make-git-rebase-safe-on-osx/), and big thanks to [@nickfalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593153/nickfalk) who pointed it out.

As for your rebase, this kind of situation is not unusual in practice.
Let's try to think through the steps of what's happening:

- When you rebase the current branch on top of another branch, git moves the HEAD to the other branch, and starts applying the unique commits you have in your current branch.
- While replaying one of those commits, you reached a conflict. You resolved it, but as a result there are no changes to commit, nothing to replay in this commit.

Practically, this means that you rejected the changes in the current commit being replayed. So, if you don't need anything from this commit, it's normal to skip it. So `git rebase --skip` makes sense here.

Comment: This would make indeed make sense if the commit in question was disregarded and none of its changes was accepted as a part of solving the conflict. Taking the below mentioned well-known bug into consideration however, it could also easily mean that you lose the intended changes in said commit...

Comment: You're right, I added this info now, and thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This was driving me crazy. Thank you very much. I would also like to note that you're awesome.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem in my project and solved by putting the [--preserve-merges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---preserve-merges) option to the rebase command. In my project, this problem was caused by a merge commit, which is an "empty commit". Using `git rebase --preserve-merges` it takes the merge commit and continues the merge without breaking the commit tree.

**EDIT:**
`--rebase-merges` is the new command option recommend at official git documentation after `--preserve-merges` deprecation.

Comment: Man, this saved my day. I was using Ubuntu, so any other answer didn't apply to me but yours. Adding the `--preserve-merges` option ended up working flawlessly as git showed me further problems that I had with my tree but that could be fixed up manually.

Comment: God bless you for this post. It resolved my problem!

Comment: That made the trick for me on Ubuntu

Comment: I got a deprecation warning to use `git rebase --rebase-merges`.  Works wonderfully!

Comment: @JohnCrawford `git rebase --rebase-merges` is the new command option recommend at official git documentation [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/2.28.0#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---preserve-merges).

Answer (score 7):

Breathe, you're not going crazy! ;-= This is a known bug where OSX (if that is indeed what you're using) is messing with git; it is detailed [by Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/blog/make-git-rebase-safe-on-osx/) (not by me).

Short story (i.e. the fix) is:

```
git config --global core.trustctime false
```

Comment: I used to have this problem all the time with huge rebases. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Yes OSX.  This fix doesn't do it :(

Comment: It is likely that this will not help with your current rebase. It is already basing itself on the existing information in the file-system. Not sure, but it might just work if you restart the rebase...

Comment: @nickfalk, thanks for answering this.  I selected another answer because that's what solves it for me but your answer can very well help someone else.

Comment: No worries Boon, hope you are 100% sure that deciding to disregard any changes your mentioned commit had was what you wanted...

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the methods but nothing worked for me. If you are not in the middle of a rebase but git keeps complaining, then try the following. This worked for me for OSX.

`rm -fr ".git/rebase-apply"`

Answer (score 1):

`git add .` will unblock you from this state, but if you resolved all conflicts by accepting the incoming changes, there is no diff to add so git thinks the conflict wasn't resolved as far as the rebase is concerned.

I took a low brow approach that worked without relying on side effects of using mysterious git config changes etc:

- Added harmless content (eg `//` on one line) to each file in conflict (to give git something to `add`)
- `git add .`
- `git rebase --continue`
- remove harmless comment

All sorted

Answer (score 0):

It could well mean that the changes are already rebased. Just check the git status.

Comment: Checked status, it's not.

Comment: How can changes be "already rebased" if I am still in the process of rebasing and I haven't finished?

Answer (score 0):

None of the above suggestions worked. I found out that I had this issue because I did a hard reset of the master branch, while my feature branch had some legacy master commits (don't asked me how - no idea :( ).

I copied my changes out to a temporary directory, deleted my feature branch, copied them back in, and restarted from scratch. Ugly but effective. Not suggested if you're trying to keep more than one commit in your feature branch. Not suggested unless you have tried *EVERYTHING ELSE*.

UPDATE: This worked, but a better approach has been pointed out to me in the comments below. Take a look.

Comment: In case of getting changes from single commit (or even few) - it's much better to put them on separate temporary local branch, then checkout your working branch, reset it to before changes, rebase if needed, then cherry pick. That's what cherry pick is for - to not copy things manually.

Comment: @AdasLesniak that's a really good point! I wish I had thought of that while I was resolving my issues last year